In the LP formulation of an MDP, how do you interpret the weights?
I understand the formulation of an MDP as an LP is given by:
$$\min_V \sum_s w(s)V(s) $$
s.t.
$$\forall s, a,  (s) ≥ (, ) + \gamma \sum_{s'}P(′|,) (′)$$
Reading around, I found that these $w$ correspond to "weights to each state if the policy can start in any state". Yet this interpretation is pretty unclear to me and I have trouble understanding what they really correspond to, from an intuitive or even mathematical point of view. Are they supposed to be known? Estimated (and is there such a thing as noise in them)? Maybe an input to the model chosen by the user and tailored to the application?
I would be happy if there is any literature on their interpretation or their choice!

Not sure about your background, but personally, I like to start with discrete problems, which, in the context of linear programming, would be integer programming cases. An interesting approach for conceiving discrete problems for MDPs is through Decision Diagrams. So, you could check these resources:

youtu.be/VkOZeewguTo
10.1007/978-3-319-42849-9 (this is a very detailed and didactic book).
Going deeper, wou could check the labeling algorithm for the Shortest Path Problem with Resource Constraints: 10.1007/0-387-25486-2_2.

